# How can I execute a query without await in React?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to understand how query works and I saw this example:

```
const citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
const snapshot = await citiesRef.where('capital', '==', true).get();
if (snapshot.empty) {
  console.log('No matching documents.');
  return;
}  

snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

The issue is that when I try to do something similar to this in my actual code I get a compile error based on **await** here's the print

[image]

and here is my code

```
const librosRef = db.collection('libros');
    const queryRef = librosRef.where('grado', '==', '4° Grado');

    const snapshot = await queryRef.get();
    
    if (snapshot.empty) 
    {
        console.log('No matching documents.');
        return;
    }  
    
    snapshot.forEach(doc => 
    {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
```

Is there a way to do this without await ? I do not Extend (might be the issue) I just code simple functions, is there any work around for this ?

Edit: I also have tried the following but it doesn't work neither

```
//relevant code
useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("libros")
        .orderBy("precio")
        .where('grado', '==', '4° Grado')
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
              const tempData = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              const data = doc.data();
              tempData.push(data);
    
              console.log(doc.data());
              console.log("Temp Data: ", tempData);
            });
            setLibros(tempData);
          });
      }, []);

//relevant code so it makes sense what is printing
<tbody>
                {libros.map((e) => (
                        
                        <tr >
                        <td>

                        <input onChange = {(event) => {
                            let checked = event.target.checked;
                        }} 
                        
                        type="checkbox" checked = "">
                        </input>
                        </td>
                        <td>{e.grado}</td>
                        <td >{e.descripcion}</td>
                        <td >{e.editorial}</td>
                        <td >${parseFloat(e.precio).toFixed(2)}</td>
                        </tr>
                     ))}
                </tbody>
```

This is what it prints

[image]

And this is how it looks in firebase

[image]

Comment: To use await, your function must be an `async` function. Also, you can replace await with a `.then(value => { /*...*/ })`. Check the `Promise` methods, or see some tutorial about handling promises

Comment: yeah I have tried the .then(value...etc) but it didn't work neither, I'll go check out the Promise methods and check some tutorials, sometimes is hard to find tutorials if I do not know the correct name of stuff, just realize "Promise" methods exist

Comment: `await` waits a `Promise` object. It's "nearly" the same as adding a `then()` to it and waiting to it asynchronously. But, for it to work, that function must be an `async function() {}`. An async function returns a `Promise` too. It's a large topic. Check this page, I think it's very complete. Not sure if it's a good entry point, thought: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Also remember than `.then()` isn't executed synchronously. Without an `await`, it will be executed later, when the database query finishes. About your edit, if you add a log at the very start of the `then()`, does it log something?

Comment: In the actual log I just realize it was printing the following (didn't check cause I'm a potato) ```Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: The query requires an index``` . what exactly you want me to log ? the ```queryRef``` ?

Comment: Anything, to see if it is running that funciton. Anyway, what you say is an error on the query, so it won't run anyway. I'm not used to work with Firebase, but if you google that error you'll find something for sure. Or maybe somebody else answers

Comment: Got it working thank you as well for the help, my only question would be what is a better practice ? **Await** or just simply use **then()**

Comment: It deppends, but usually await is more legible if you have to wait for it. If you don't use await, you end up chaining code inside the `then`, and it may become a bit messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, just modifying the `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const response = await db.collection("libros")
      .orderBy("precio")
      .where('grado', '==', '4° Grado')
      .get();
    
    const tempData = [];
    response.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      tempData.push(data);
      
      console.log(doc.data());
      console.log("Temp Data: ", tempData);
    });
    setLibros(tempData);
  })();
}, []);
```

Basically, we're using an IIFE in the `useEffect` to be able to use the async.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work instead it gave me an error ```Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: The query requires an index.```

Comment: That error must have a link as well which you can use to create the required index.

Comment: This is the first time I see this Indexes I have no idea what it is, I'm gonna give it a quick check, thanks for the help!